# Retornar nome do aluno na consulta junto com a matricula - python e django admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-queryset

Classe Base:

```
class Base(models.Model):
IncPor = models.IntegerField('Incluido Por', null=True, blank=True)
AltPor = models.IntegerField('Alterado Por', null=True, blank=True)
IncEm = models.DateTimeField('Incluido Em', auto_now_add=True)
AltEm = models.DateTimeField('Alterado Em', auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Classe Pessoa:

```
class Pessoa(Base):    
nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=150)
data_nascimento = models.DateField('Data de nascimento', null=True)
pessoa_status = models.BooleanField('Pessoa ativa?', default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

Classe Aluno:

```
class Aluno(models.Model):
pessoa = models.ForeignKey("Pessoa", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
matricula = models.IntegerField('Matricula', unique=True)
aluno_status = models.BooleanField('Aluno ativo? ', default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.matricula)
```

Gostaria de retornar na consulta no arquivo `admin.py` a **matrícula** e **nome** do aluno.
O relacionamento está `1 - n`. Uma pessoa pode ter varias matrículas, e uma matricula pode ser uma pessoa.

```
@admin.register(Aluno)
class AdminAluno(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('matricula', )
```

Erro:

> ERRORS: <class 'core.admin.AdminAluno'>: (admin.E108) The value of
> 'list_display[1]' refers to 'nome', which is not a callable, an
> attribute of 'AdminAluno', or an  attribute or method on 'core.Aluno'.
>
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recuperar o nome da class `Pessoa`

Utilizei como solução no `admin.py`

```
list_display = ('get_nome',)


def get_nome(self, obj):
    return obj.pessoa.nome
get_nome.short_description = 'Nome'
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode exibir o nome e a matrícula do aluno na página Admin do Django da seguinte forma:

Classe Aluno:

```
class Aluno(models.Model):
pessoa = models.ForeignKey("Pessoa", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
matricula = models.IntegerField('Matricula', unique=True)
aluno_status = models.BooleanField('Aluno ativo? ', default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "Nome: {} - Matrícula: {}".format(self.pessoa.nome,self.matricula)
```

Comment: Certo, dessa forma consigo capturar o nome. Mas gostaria de exibir o nome na grid do admin.py